# Load all images from one folder

Tags: jquery, css

```
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height =  getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages)
```

I copied above code from https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/. It works.

But when, I change path `'<img src="https://placekitten.com/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';` to `'<img src="images/photos/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';` it not works. In consolse shows error like - 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

all file names are like 'IMG_0928_F...' and jpg format.

Please tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: here `width` and `height` will give you random number but your images are save like `'IMG_0928_F...` i am not seeing you have apppend `IMG_` to your path .Also , are you sure all random number generated from your code has image exist ?

Comment: @Swati, yes all random numbers generated and path seen in html file but images not shown. and I also tried to append file name to path but not works.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there are no images that exist with that name because your filenames are like "'IMG_0928_F...' and jpg format.".

Say we want a picture with the size 314 x 221. We fill in 314 for the width and 221 for the height. The site placekitten has a folder named "314" and an image called 221.jpg (you can check this if you want, just try to save the image from the site). Unless you have the same folders (named from 200 to 400) and the same image names (named again form 200 to 400) you won't get the same result as above. You arleady said that the file names are like " 'IMG_0928_F...' and jpg format." which means that this funciton won't be able to find the right images.

Depending on what you want to do you have to either change your code, or change the names from your directories and files. If you don't care about the size and just want to loop through 25 images I'd recommend the following:

change

`allImages += '<img src="images/photos/'+width+'/'+height+'" alt="pretty kitty">';`

to

`allImages += '<img src="images/photos/IMG_00'+ i +'_F.jpg" alt="pretty kitty">';`

In this case (if you don't change your loop) you will only get the images 0000 to 0024.

If you want to have the exact same results with the same code, than you need to start creating a lot of folders and renaming a lot of images.

Comment: I tried both, create folder and change file names as in you explnation but not works and your code shows error in console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string'

Comment: @Ramesh Ah yes I fixed a typo. If you still have the original directories and filenames you can use this code ` allImages += '<img src="images/photos/IMG_00'+ i +'_F.jpg" alt="pretty kitty">'; `

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. As per your starting explanation and from 'https://placeholder.com/' I learnt more that need to create folders (named from 200 to 400) and the same image names (named again form 200 to 400). It will take more time, So I changed my jquery as below and create one folder and changed file names 1, 2, 3... as numbers and it works fine.

Comment: var dir = "images/photos/"; 
var fileextension = ".jpg"; 
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 1;
 var n = 11; 
 
 for(i=1;i<n;i++){
  imageloop(i);
 };
});
function imageloop(i){
 $("<img />").attr('src', dir + i + fileextension ).appendTo("#photos");
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);